# In M1 Machine Ventura13.3 - Xcode 14.3 build error with UnDefined Symbol on all Pods framework

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-m1, xcode14.3, ios16.4

In M1 Machine Ventura 13.3 - installed Xcode 14.3 and try to build the existing project.

1. On build getting an error with UnDefined Symbol on all Pods framework.

   [image: Build Error]
2. On the Xcode14.3 release notes I read that in the deprecated section, it does not support the rosetta config any more, previously in Xcode 14.2 I enabled build with the rosetta option and it's successfully built.
3. So I revert to old XCode 14.2 to release my pending project for the deliverable. In that case, the build with the simulator gets the same issue even if the rosetta option enables but in the device, it's built successfully.
4. On the next day I try with Xcode 14.3 as a separate application downloaded from apple downloads. When build the project i receive an error as **Missing file libarclite_iphoneos.a (Xcode 14.3)**
5. On google, need to update pod library to latest OS target as 11.0

   **post_install do |installer|
   installer.generated_projects.each do |project|
   project.targets.each do |target|
   target.build_configurations.each do |config|
   config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '11.0'
   end
   end
   end   end**

   Close the project and run **pod install** in the terminal.
6. After pod installation, start to build the project again and received an error in the popup window as below.

   [image: Error in popup]

   Upon clicking learn more it redirects to https://developer.apple.com/documentation/technotes/tn3117-resolving-build-errors-for-apple-silicon
7. I updated the architecture in the build settings as mentioned in the link. Attached is the VALID_ARCHS screenshot

   [image]
8. When running the project again with the same error popup window, this time I click on **Build for Rosetta** option, and the project successfully build. The Simulator's name changed to Rosetta.

   [image]
9. now app successfully build and run in the iOS 16.4 simulator.

How do I work my app in an M1 machine without building with Rosetta?
Is right to build an app with Rosetta in 14.3?

Comment: I am getting this same for Stripe framework. Build failed because Stripe.swiftmodule is missing a required architecture. Would you like to build for Rosetta instead?
Is there any solution so we can run this on Apple silicon only ?

Comment: @MiteshDobareeya for a quick fix, I build with Rosetta and need to work on building with Apple silicon. I found steps to enable build with Apple Silicon, will update once I found the solution, thanks.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Can you please share those steps if possible, so that I can try them on my end. Thank you.

Comment: Anyone here having similar issues with intel chipsets? Xcode 14.3

Answer (score 8):

In the error popup window, mention **You can control the visibility of architecture-specific run destinations in the product > Destination menu.**

[image: Xcode Build Erro]

When selecting the Product and Destination menu, display as below image

[image]

When selecting show both, display both architecture simulator

[image]

Comment: can this harm anything? performance, speed?

Answer (score 0):

For me the cause was the fact I ended up trying to build an iPhone unit test target on a TV destination. The unit testing target was part of a scheme that contained multiple targets, so Xcode allowed this incompatible combination.